# SELECT CASE and use in a CONDITION

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Is it possible to have a SELECT CASE STATEMENT and then use THAT column in a WHERE condition?

something like:

```
LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT student_id 
, 
CASE 
WHEN (
consent_type = 'Medicaid'
//condtion here
)
THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END AS refusal 
FROM students_refusal

) as refusals USING(student_id)
```

This will output a yes/no column. Now I want to just output the refusal column that has a "No" value in it. I tried using

`WHERE refusal = 'No'`. It just says column refusal does not exist. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a subquery:

```
select * from (
   select case when someField=1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as f
     from sometable ) tb
 where tb.f = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"WHERE refusal = 'No'. It just says column refusal does not exist. How to do this?"*

you can't reference `refusal` in `WHERE clause` so I think you should change like this:

```
IF (consent_type = 'Medicaid' //condtion here, 'Yes', 'No') AS refusal
FROM students_refusal
WHERE
    IF (consent_type = 'Medicaid' //condtion here, 'Yes', 'No') = 'No'
```

BTW, I think `IF()` is better than `CASE` in this case.